# Is it possible to view jar files in Android Studio Project Explorer?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I'd like to see if class exists in jar. Is it possible to view jar files in Android Studio Project Explorer and how?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes of course, You can browse it like normal directory.

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196335/how-to-find-every-version-of-android-support-libraries-source-code/35196766#35196766

Comment: Thank for answer! I've added screen. Why for guava lib it doesn't allow to view?

Comment: Sync your project , I am able to see it after syncing it.

Comment: I've synced. Doen't help. Strange lib. I have problem with it. Compiler says like this lib guava doen't contain file but as it seen from screen it exists (http://joxi.ru/bmozPlvuMo64kr

Comment: Which version of Android Studio you are using, Its working well on 1.5.1 the same jar guva-18.jar .

Comment: The latest one. Android Studio 2.0 Preview 9. guava-18.jar

Comment: Hey @KirylIvanou, please adjust your question which is starting right after the Image, it feels little uncomfortable :) 

Answer (score 0):

I understood why unable to see lib files (in my case guava) because it wasn't compiled (or added on runtime as it seems)! I got error on rumtime for that guava library

Error:Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: 
javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor 
could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap

where com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap is from guava

for example, if

```
compile files('libs\ugava.jar')
```

performs successfully in build.gradle than this library is able for its files to view in Project browser