# See changes in Android Support Library sources between two versions

Tags: android, git, android-support-library, android-source

I want to clone repository for Android Support Library and see what has been changed between version 24.1.1 and 24.2.0.

I know that repository is located [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support) but:

1. Its latest commits are dated by July 1 though latest support library release 24.2.0 was in August.
2. There are no tags like support library versions 24.1.1, 24.2.0, etc.

How can I just see what commits were made between versions 24.1.1 and 24.2.0?

Comment: this might help https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/

Answer (score 7):

There are tags ([`android/platform_frameworks_support/releases`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/releases)), but they are specific to the `android/platform_frameworks_support` repo.

The [Support Library Revision History](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) does mention 24.x.y revisions, and it says the v4 support librairies have been [splitted in modules like](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) `support-compat`.
You can see one of those modules in [dandar3/android-support-compat](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-compat) which mentions being it based on `ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-compat/24.2.0/support-compat-24.2.0.aar`

So we are talking about a completely different set of git repositories:
See [`dandar3/android-support-README`](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-README).

So pick any of those support repos, and [see what has changes between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552353/6309).
You can do it directly on GitHub:

https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v4/compare/24.1.1...24.2.0

---

[The Book "Gradle for Android"](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Uyw0CgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA39&ots=0yXqW8_RNz&dq=%22ANDROID_SDK%2Fextras%22%20repository&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q=%22ANDROID_SDK/extras%22%20repository&f=false), from [Kevin Pelgrims](https://twitter.com/kevinpelgrims), mentions:

> New Android projects have a dependency on the Android Support Library by default.
>   When installing the Google repositories using the SDK manager, two Maven repositories are created on your hard drive:
>
> - `ANDROID_SDK/extras/google/m2repository`
> - `ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/m2repository`
>
> This is where Gradle gets the libraries provided by Google, such as the Android Support Library and Google Play Services.

Again, the sources (as Git repos) might not be available, but you still can get those projects through the [SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html).

Comment: I'm looking for official repository with original sources not decompiled from aar. But your answer is still helpful, thanks, up-voted. That releases tags you mention are tags I'm looking for though they have specific names. To find out real revision name we have to look at `ext.supportVersion` in `build.gradle`. it has `24.0.1` value in the latest commit. So the only question left is where are commits for the revisions released after `24.0.1`.

Comment: @mixel I suspect if someone took the time to decompile an aar, those sources might not be readily available. Still looking though.

Comment: I'm afraid of this too. So sad.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Awarded bounty to you. But I'm still looking for the official repositories and hoping to get response from Support Library Team (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39315958/746347).