# Android Support Library repository management and release cycle

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-source

I recently searched for an answer to [how to see changes in Android Support Library between two versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39271969/746347) and found out that I do not understand few things regarding Android Support Library repository management and release cycle.

1. Where are commits for library revisions `24.1.0`, `24.1.1`, `24.2.0`? Does Google have internal repository? If so then how often latest commits are pushed to public repository from internal one?
2. [Support Library Revision History](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) says that the v4 Support Library has been split into several smaller modules. Does it mean that each module now has separate repository. If so then where are these repositories?
3. How does Android Support Library team manage repository tags? Why do tags contain Android version like `android-4.1.1` if each support library release is supposed to work on all Android versions above some version?

Comment: 3. Seems not answerable by anyone except the Framework Team from Google.

Comment: @Enzokie There may be contributors from community that have experience with AOSP and specifically with Android Support Library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new Google Maven repo `https://maven.google.com`.

For example:

`https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/design/26.0.1/design-26.0.1-sources.jar`

Since that repo is new from support library `26.0.1`, I'm not sure about old versions... But, for old versions, you can download the sources via SDK Manager, *then* find them in `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/extras/android/m2repository/`.

I know you're not looking for sources. But this might help...