# How to checkout the source code of android-support library for a special revision?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I wan't to build the support-library 25.4.0, I have checkout branch 'ub-supportlib-master', but I do not know how to check the source code for a special revision.
Neither branches nor tags contains revision information.

Comment: a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196335/how-to-find-every-version-of-android-support-libraries-source-code